# Highmaps: how do I detect the target of enableDoubleClickZoomTo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highmaps

I have a map of the United States rendered in Highmaps, with `enableDoubleClickZoomTo` set to `true`. I've gotten stuck trying to discern what state a user has double clicked on to zoom the map, and wondered if there was information buried in the `redraw` event that would help me calculate this.

Here's a fiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/tjnicolaides/x8q1d1cs/

```
$('#container').highcharts('Map', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            redraw: function (event) {
                console.log(event);
                console.log(this.getSelectedPoints());
            }
        }
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        enableDoubleClickZoomTo: true
    },

    series: [{
        data: data,
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all'],
        joinBy: 'hc-key',
        allowPointSelect: true,
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            },
            select: {
                color: 'purple'
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

When I console.log `event` after double clicking on a state, I'm getting a large object with information about the state of the entire chart.

If I single click to select a state, and then double click to zoom in on it, I get information about the state from `this.getSelectedPoints()` - however, it is not reasonable to expect that anything will be selected prior to zooming. In some maps, it may be disabled altogether. I included it here as a demonstration of the type of output I was originally hoping to get from `redraw`. Calculating a postal code, state name, or index to filter the original series with would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to detect that point by wrapping `Pointer.onContainerDblClick`, like this:

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Pointer.prototype, "onContainerDblClick", function (p, event) {
        console.log(this.chart.hoverPoint); // hovered point - may not exist, e.g. when clicking on the blank space
        p.call(this, event);
    });
})(Highcharts)
```

And live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x8q1d1cs/8/

Comment: bingo. Thanks so much!